# Разделить переменную на несколько, SPLIT?

Tags: java, android

Я ЧАЙНИК ! Не ругайтесь сильно !
дело в том что символ делителя ещё и повторяется в самом значении несколько раз. На выходе имею кашу((( Как обозначить символ иначе????

```
    String StartEnd = jsonPropose.getString("addr");
    String[] massAdr = StartEnd.split(",");
    Log.e("<<<<<<<>>>>>>>>>>>>>ADDR......SPLIT_______1:" +massAdr[0]);
    Log.e("<<<<<<<>>>>>>>>>>>>>ADDR......SPLIT_______2:" +massAdr[1]);
```

Вот что в переменной:
 <<<<<<<>>>>>>>>>>>>>ADDR:["Победы бульвар, 6","Боевая 5-й проезд, 4"]
А это результат разделения:
 <<<<<<<>>>>>>>>>>>>>ADDR......SPLIT_______1:["Победы бульвар
 <<<<<<<>>>>>>>>>>>>>ADDR......SPLIT_______2: 6"

Comment: У Вас здесь массив в формате JSON. Найдите парсер JSON для Java и используйте его.

Comment: Добавил парсер. Не доходит, как применить..? Не могли бы подсказать? Огромное спасибо!

Comment: Я не программирую на Java. Попробуйте посмотреть, например, здесь: https://github.com/fabienrenaud/java-json-benchmark или поискать "Java parse json string"

Comment: каково содержимое StartEnd и что вы хотите иметь на выходе?

Comment: String StartEnd = jsonPropose.getString("addr");
        String[] massAdr = StartEnd.split(",");
        Log.e("<<<<<<<>>>>>>>>>>>>>ADDR......SPLIT_______1:" +massAdr[0] +massAdr[1]);
        Log.e("<<<<<<<>>>>>>>>>>>>>ADDR......SPLIT_______2:" +massAdr[2]+massAdr[3]);
        String SummStart = addPrefix+massAdr[0]+massAdr[1];
        String SummEnd = addPrefix+massAdr[2]+massAdr[3];     В StartEnd адрес записан целиком. Затем я его всё-таки разделил на 2 полноценных. Но, припопытке запросить по ним координаты - появляются вопросы... Придётся выложить новый вопрос, т.к. сюда не влезает.